# Can I use two different Eclipse (IDE java) versions on same project?

Tags: java, eclipse, objectaid

I'm developing a project with Eclipse 4.21, unfortunately this version doesn't allow ObjectAid to work properly, I don't know why. After many attempts, I found out that ObjectAid doesn't work anymore after Eclipse 4.19.

I don't want to reinstall and configure Eclipse again for my project. So, can I have two Eclipse opened on same workspace / same project  at same time? Using one (4.21) to develop and one (4.19) just to generate UML class diagram (using objectaid) without problems.

Comment: If you look at the recent questions in the [tag:objectaid] tag it appears that the company has failed and the code will no longer works at all regardless of the Eclipse release.

Comment: Yes i know, but what has that to do with ?   this appears to be more a problem concerning Eclipse .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't run two versions of Eclipse at the same time accessing a single workspace. The second Eclipse you try to start will refuse to access the workspace saying it is already in use.

Trying to run an older version of Eclipse on a workspace that has been modified by a newer version will also produce an error.

You can run multiple versions on separate workspaces.